# How to prove that $A+B$ is not closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$..

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let A and B be subsets of $R^n$. then
Consider the sets here A+B=$\lbrace a+b:a\in A ,b\in B\rbrace$

W = $\lbrace (x, y) : x > 0; y > 0\rbrace$

X = $\lbrace (x, y): x\in \mathbb{R}; y = 0\rbrace$

Y = $\lbrace (x, y): xy = 1\rbrace$

Z = $\lbrace (x, y): |x| \leq 1,|y| \leq 1\rbrace$

Which of the following statements are true?

a. The set W + X is open.

b. The set X + Y is closed.

c. The set Y + Z is closed.

Question: I can guess geometrically that the set W+X is upper half plane so is open. Again by using the thm that " If A is compact and B is closed then A+B is closed", I am able to prove option c. But i dont know how to approach option b.
I have thought of using dimension argument but here Y is not a vector subspace so what can be done? Is there any general approach?

Comment: What is $+$? Do you mean union or vector sum?

Comment: it is vector sum

Comment: So you are saying $X+Y=Y?$ How can X+Y=Y?

Comment: Its a Question from NBHM 2014. and its answer is given to be a and c

Comment: @anonymous your description of $X+Y$ is incorrect: you are simply describing $Y$ instead. Here's a hint: addition by an element of $X$ is just horizontal translation. So if you translate $Y$ horizontally, and take the union of all such translations, what do you get?

Comment: If (x+w, y + z) in X + Y.  (x,y) in X and (w,z) in Y.  Then y = 0 but z can be any real but 0 so y + z =z.  w = 1/z but x can be any real so x+w= x + 1/z can be any real. So X + Y = {(x,y)| y ne 0} which is not closed.  Right?

Comment: yes @fleablood. thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute $X + Y$. It's clear that all $(x,y)$ in $Y$ have $y \neq 0$ and adding $y=0$ (for a point from $X$) doesn't change that. So $X + Y \subseteq \{(x,y): y \neq 0\}$.

If $(x,y)$ is such that $y \neq 0$, then $(x,y) = (x - \frac{1}{y}, 0) + (\frac{1}{y},y) \in X + Y$, so the reverse inclusion also holds.

Now b) should be clear.

Comment: thnks. Its clear now..

Answer (score 0):

To explicitly add $X+Y$ you'd use the fact that given a $y\ne 0$ you may conclude what $x$ is in $Y$ and you can always find a $x$ in $X$ so that they sum up to the required $(x,y)$.

On the other hand if $y=0$ you can find no pairs in $X$ and $Y$ that add upp.

Consequently the set $X+Y$ is every pair except those with $y=0$. So no $X+Y$ is **not** closed.